# Display Data from ajax Json to ul tag in web forms asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, json, xmlhttprequest

I have this function to get data from a database using JSON

```js
    function BindMembers() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/test.asmx/test1",
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/Json; Charset= Utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    var list = "";
                    $.each(data.data, function (index, item) {
                        list += "<li class='text-secondary p-1'><a class='btn-link text-secondary'><b>" + item.Id + "</b>" + ", " + "<span class='font-italic'><small>" + item.Id + "</small></span><small><a href='#' Onclick='Delete(" + item.Id + ")'> <i class='float-right far fa-trash-alt'></i></a></small></a>" + "</li>";
                    });
                    $("#list").html(list);
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response);
                }
            });
        }
```

And this my HTML code:

```html
    <ul id="list">
       <li></li>
    </ul>
```

I need to bind `<div>` tag from the function.

Someone have any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**
Change the <div> to an  because <li> can only be added to <ul>, <ol> or <menu> as in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li

Comment: i need to bind the tag div in my html from this function BindMembers()

Comment: I am sorry isn't the div already in your HTML? So filling it inside the function which you do should also render it to the HTML. My question is does the data not appear? Maybe change the div to an <ul> element because you are writing <li> elements into a <div> element and <li> can only added to <ol> <ul> or <menu> as in https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li